# URL rewriting QUERY_STRING?

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string

I've tried and looked for lot of your posts,
cannot get it working yet.

all URL from the site I have a simple PHP config like this example :

`http://www.example.com/index.php?page=pagename`

I'm wondering if I can hide Quesry_String like this :

`http://www.example.com/pagename/`

In the server config (apache 2.2 using virtual host without .htaccess) :

```
    DocumentRoot "/home/account/www/www.mysite.com/"
    Options -MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine On

    ## Rewrite 301 old Quesry_string (?p => ?page) ##
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/$ /?page=%1 [R=301,L]

    ## Trying to hide query_string (not working) ##
    #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+) [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^/$ /%1 [R=301,L]
    #result => http://www.www.mysite.com/pagename?page=pagename (404)

    ## Rewrite 301 old page names ##
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=oldpagename$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /?page=pagename/ [R=301,L]

    ## Remove index.php from url ##
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

    #Rewrite 301 index.html to root /
    RewriteRule ^/index.htm?$ index.html [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/index.html?$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

I guess I'm almost there, thank you for your help.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you i guess

> > RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

Comment: I added it at the end while commenting :  
  
        ## Remove index.php from url ##  
        #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)  
        #RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]  
  
it does not rewrite  
I will try it without the other rules